# For which values of $p$ does $\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\log(n))(\log\log(n))\dotsm(\log_{j}(n))(\log_{j+1}(n))^p}$ converge?

Tags: calculus

For which values of p does $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\log(n))(\log\log(n))\dotsm(\log_{j}(n))(\log_{j+1}(n))^p}$$
 converge?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) to reduce the terms recursively, and show that its convergence is equivalent to $p > 1$.